# Export DateTime String to CSV is truncating seconds

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a list of elements to excel through MVC FileResult by creating byte[] from the string builder. I have formatted the DateTime to custom format

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss  example 15/06/2009 13:45:30
```

Here the issue is the datetime is getting truncated in the excel as

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm    example 15/06/2009 13:45
```

Here is the code for same

```
public FileResult Export(ParametersArchive parameterArchive)
{
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", "Name", "Parameter", "Status"
                , "Actual Value", "Date", Environment.NewLine);
   foreach (ParameterArchive p in parameterArchive.Parameters)
   {
      builder = builder.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", p.Name, 
        p.ParamName, p.AlertTypeId, p.ParamValue, 
         p.DateAdded.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), Environment.NewLine);
   }

     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=Archive.csv");
     Response.ContentType = "application/text/csv";
     byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
     return new FileContentResult( buffer, "application/text/csv");         
}
```

Is there anything i am missing here? Any clue would be great.